# Kendo MVC how to bind custom toolbar action in child grids

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

**Objective**: bind detail grids' custom toolbar actions to pass the id of the parent row to the client-side script.

#### master-detail grids

Each master row has 0-many details, displayed upon expanding the row. The details are another grid bound to the parent row using kendo's client templating.

[image: grids]

#### master grid

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ConfigurationRuleViewModel>()
          .Name("configurationRuleGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          ...)
          // detail grid
          .ClientDetailTemplateId("configRuleDetailTemplate")
        )
```

#### detail viewmodel

`ConfigurationId` is the property needed to be bound and passed to the add button's `onclick` event of the subgrid for each row.

```
  public class RuleViewModel
  {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ConfigurationId { get; set; }
    ...
  }
```

#### detail grid (kendo client template)

```
   <script id="configRuleDetailTemplate" type="text/kendo-template">
       @(Html.Kendo().Grid<RuleViewModel>()
           .Name("grid_#=Id#")
           .Columns(columns =>
            ...
           )//
           .ToolBar(commands =>
                    commands.Template("<a class='btnNewRule k-button k-button-icontext' onclick='loadNewRule(\\#=ConfigurationId \\#)' title='Add new rule'></span>Add</a>"))
           ...
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
           ...
           )
          .ToClientTemplate())
  </script>
```

#### what I tried

- binding to the buttons individually use the document.ready event

  //attempt 1 (tried many different selectors, same result)
     var addBtns = $("a.btnNewRule");

  // can't find buttons 
     if($.isArray(addBtns))
     {
        $(addBtns).each(function(_, btn){
           btn.on("click",function () { 
              loadNewRule(this); 
           });
        });
     }

  //attempt 2
     // finding from the grid context, toolbars
     // still can't find buttons 
     ruleGrid.find(".k-grid-toolbar").on("click", ".btnNewRule", function (e) 
     {
         loadNewRule(e);
     });

testing the selectors in the dev console show that the elements are not available at the time so the only option appears to be binding in the details grid using a custom toolbar - rendering race condition.

- current implementation: attempting to bind the click event using the viewmodel property `ConfigurationId`

  onclick='loadNewRule(\#=ConfigurationId \#)'

**BUT**, the syntax is bogus and generates an [expected] error:

```
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

What is the correct way to bind the property in the client template.

NOTE: the client template uses inline editing but the add will use a popup with custom editors, hence the need to bind as attempting.

Open to different ways to achieve the objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the ghetto way to do it but it works. Anyone have a better, more kendo way please post. A solution, is to pass the button reference `this` to the load function which uses the button to locate the row that contains the parent element (which contains the property needed).

#### custom toolbar, `onlick` definition

```
  //detail grid command definitions
  ...
   commands.Template("<a class='btnNewRule k-button k-button-icontext' onclick='loadNewRule(this)' title='Add new rule'></span>Add</a>"))
  ...
```

#### js helper function to find the parent id

common pattern to find related items in kendo

```
   function getCurrentParentConfigurationId(source) {
        const row = $(source).closest("tr");
        const grid = $("#configurationRuleGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        const dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

        return dataItem.Id;
   }
```